# Tukey HSD test for normal residual and heterogenous variance

Tags: anova

Can we apply the Tukey HSD test if the residual of the ANOVA has normal distribution but the heterogeneous variance?

Comment: Tukey HSD relies heavily on equal variances. Many ANOVA procedures do also. However, some do not: For example, in R, `oneway.test` does a "ANOVA" that corrects DF for unequal variances, and there are nonparametric procedures loosely called "ANOVAs".